# Which refresh rate should I use from GetDisplayModeList?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

DirectX 'returns' multiple 'matching' display modes from this call:

```
dxgiAdapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numDisplayModes, displayModeList);
```

I printed out all the matching modes that also match my resolution:

> 17.20:34+443 Mode 51: Size => 1920x1080, Refresh Rate => 50000/1000
>
> 17.20:34+443 Mode 52: Size => 1920x1080, Refresh Rate => 50000/1000
>
> 17.20:34+443 Mode 53: Size => 1920x1080, Refresh Rate => 59940/1000
>
> 17.20:34+443 Mode 54: Size => 1920x1080, Refresh Rate => 59940/1000
>
> 17.20:34+443 Mode 55: Size => 1920x1080, Refresh Rate => 60000/1001
>
> 17.20:34+443 Mode 56: Size => 1920x1080, Refresh Rate => 60000/1001

So which numerator / denominator pair is the 'right' one to pass to the swap chain?

Comment: 60000/1001 = 59.94005994, so presumably the two second pairs are actually the same refresh race, just expressed differently?

Comment: Ah yeah, it seems that way. Didn't spot that! Doesn't explain the first pair though. Or why they're even in pairs.

Comment: First pair is clearly the 50Hz option (TV and such in Europe). 59.94 is the TV frequency used by NTSC.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a windowed swap-chain, the refresh rate is ignored, and the OS will continue using whatever the current system refresh rate is.  If you are creating a full-screen swap-chain, you can select any of the valid modes returned by the API - whatever you prefer. Note however that if your selected mode differs from the current system display mode, you will trigger a "mode change" which results in a visible flicker of the display.

The reason the API returns multiple identical modes is likely due to a display driver bug.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Is there some way I can determine the current display mode?

Comment: @Motig You can use DwmGetCompositionTimingInfo to get the right timing, and you should be able to use 0 for the width and height to use the current display resolution.  You're probably better off with windowed full-screen though (use WS_POPUP for style and CW_USEDEFAULT for size).  That guarantees no flickering, and that alt+tab and notifications will continue to work.

Comment: @MooseBoys Is there a way to use a different refresh rate, than the current system's refresh rate, on a windowed swap-chain? Perhaps with DwmSetPresentParameters? Or using another trick?